# Magento 2.2.3 Getting an Error While Saving Product?

Tags: magento2, product, admin, database, catalog

I am facing one issue while saving/update the product in magento 2.2.3 CE

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1,
>   query was: UPDATE catalog_product_entity set updated_at='2018-07-03
>   05:47:23' where entity_id =

Note:- able to save the product but getting an error like as shown in the below w screen shot

[image]

Could you please suggest how to overcome this error?

**Exception log:-**

> main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1, query was: UPDATE catalog_product_entity set
>   updated_at='2018-07-25 06:29:22' where entity_id =
>   {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42000):
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1,
>   query was: UPDATE catalog_product_entity set updated_at='2018-07-25
>   06:29:22' where entity_id = at
>   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:2228

Comment: Clear all log files and then try to save the product.
post here what log says after saying product

Comment: Hi @nagaraju help me if u have any idea about this task: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/232375/49102

Answer (score 1):

Nagaraju. The issue with Saving product is related to the Kensium/Amconnector module.

Next

```
Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1, query was: UPDATE catalog_product_entity set updated_at='2018-08-10 08:31:33' where entity_id = in /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(93): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

#1 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)

#2 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)

#3 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE catalog_...', Array)

#4 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(517): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE catalog_...', Array)

#5 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(580): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('UPDATE catalog_...', Array)

#6 /srv/public_html/app/code/Kensium/Amconnector/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php(1146): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('UPDATE catalog_...')

#7 /srv/public_html/app/code/Kensium/Amconnector/Observer/SaveProductUpdatedAt.php(46): Kensium\Amconnector\Model\ResourceModel\Product->updateProductDate(NULL)

#8 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(72): Kensium\Amconnector\Observer\SaveProductUpdatedAt->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
```

Definitely not a Magento 2 core issue or difficulties with hosting. Hope this helps. Cheers.